# Maximum interval for GC.Collect to get valid MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize values on AppDomain

Tags: .net, appdomain, .net-4.7.2

I have a windows service written in c# which uses `AppDomain` instances for separation purposes. To monitor and manage the `AppDomain` instances, I use the *“Application Domain Resource Monitoring”* option.

To get a valid value for the `AppDomain.MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize`, I have to call `GC.Collect`. Since this is a heavy operation, I only want to call it as little as necessary.

Is there a constant or another way to determine what the interval is, which is necessary to not letting running the `MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize` property to be reset and returning zero, instead of the last detected amount of memory?

I surely can try to get the interval by trial and error, but there is no guarantee, that the values I get, are in other environments the same.
Or is there an other way altogether to get this information in a reliable manner?

Comment: There is no interval.  The value gets updated when a GC completes, which is driven only by memory usage.  Or GC.Collect().  Not practical for fine-grained monitoring purposes, just don't call Collect().  You'd be off at most by about 16MB, more for serverGC.

Comment: [Remarks section of `MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.monitoringsurvivedmemorysize?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) also tells, that value is accurate only after full blocking collection

Comment: @Hans Passant: After reading some posts from other people concerning this matter, I was under the impression, that the property resets to zero after a while of no GC-operation. If I understand your comment correct, this is not the case and explicitly only GC operations change the property's value at all. If you make your comment an answer, I would be happy to accept it.